# Check who sends message

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm very bad at python (and programming). I'm trying to create simple "forward-client".

I want my telegram client forward messages to `saved messages`, so i did this:

```
api_id = ****
api_hash = '****'

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   @client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing='true', incoming='true'))
   async def handler(event):
      await event.message.forward_to('me')
   client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Everything works fine, but i want to forward only my messages and messages from users. Not from groups or public channels.

How i can do that? Can't find anything in documentation

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close and just need to add `chats` argument on `events.NewMessage`. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.newmessage.NewMessage) for more

Here's the code you want:

```py
api_id = ****
api_hash = '****'

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   @client.on(events.NewMessage(outgoing='true', incoming='true', chats=[xxxxx, xxxx]))
   async def handler(event):
      await event.message.forward_to('me')
   client.run_until_disconnected()
```

`chats` argument will need a list of entities ( read more about entities [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html) )

If you are looking for a simple solution you can always use this telegram bot I've made [@tg_feedbot](https://t.me/tg_feedbot)

This is a bot used for forwarding messages from one/multiple groups to others. The way it works is by using your telegram account and when a message comes - if you have configured it so - it sees it and rewrites it to the channels you want. You can edit the way the message looks, filter it, delay and change words.

It's a free solution for automating `Telegram User API`  and it has a simple to use interface together with [documentation](https://telefeed.readthedocs.io/)